# Hostname is undefined in Logback/SLF4J in production environment

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm using Logback/SLF4J to do logging, and it works like a charm on my Mac development machine.

I have the following pattern used for mail appender subject:

```
<subject>[ERROR] ${HOSTNAME} : %msg</subject>
```

When running the service on my Mac, I receive a subject like this:

```
macbook-pro.localhost : Error message
```

When I run the service on a Debian (Lenny) VPS, I get the following email subject

```
HOSTNAME_IS_UNDEFIENED : Error message
```

Typing `hostname` in command line for both Mac and Debian machine produces the following:

```
mac: macbook-pro.localhost
debian: s1.myservice.com
```

I'd like to see the `s1.myservice.com` in email subject.

Comment: On your debian machine what is the contents of /etc/hostname ?

Comment: content of /etc/hostname is s1

Comment: pinging s1 results on unknown host, same is true for s1.myservice.com

Answer (score 4):

Logback [gets the value of HOSTNAME](https://github.com/ceki/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/util/ContextUtil.java) with [InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29). Check what the following code prints on your server:

```
import java.net.*;

final InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("hostAddress: " + localHost.getHostAddress());
System.out.println("hostName: " + localHost.getHostName());
```